# Can someone help me identify these? (possibly pest)

Tags: pest-control, pest

recently I have found a lot of these things around exterior of my house. I don't think they are wing clippings but I'd really appreciate if someone could tell me what these are. Picture taken on concrete. They are tiny but thick for wings (I hope). Thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

As requested. Please see picture with the ruler. It is in centimeter. At the 3rd mark, it is the thickness.
I also broke it in piece noted between 5th and 6th centimeter mark. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you take another picture with a ruler placed next to them for scale? Also, how thick are they? Some of them appear significantly lighter along one side than along the other - are they translucent with the concrete showing through, or is that their actual color?

Comment: Please see the new pictures. Thanks.

Comment: My first guess was some type of Helicopter Seeds (Samara Fruit), but I've never seen any that small.

Comment: @MosheKatz OP should look at the trees near their property to see if they're seeds. It might be that animals are eating them and they're significantly immature.

Comment: definitely looks like seeds ... probably from a conifer, such as a pine or a spruce ... how can you post a question without picking one up and examining it?

Comment: They thought it is bugs?